# Spring application : obtaining server path, within a Quartz job

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I'm working with JBoss 4 & Spring. In a web application, I use Quartz scheduler to perform some scheduled task. In a Quartz job, I would like to get the server path Is it possible ? If yes, how ?

PS: Some context
I need the server path in Quartz job, because that job would send emails. The emails contains links to the website my application serves, and to build proper URLs, I need a server path. Hardcoding the server path is a no-no, as the application is deployed on various servers.

Comment: What do you mean by "server path"?  That could mean various things.

Comment: The root path for all URL to the website, like `http://fluffy.org`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no sensible way to get the data from inside the Quartz job, so it will have to be the other way around. Have a global configuration bean, call it ServerConfig or whatever. Let it implement [`ServletContextAware`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/web/context/ServletContextAware.html), then it is automatically notified when a web context is started up.

```
public class ServerConfig implements ServletContextAware{
    private String serverRootUrl;
    public String getServerRootUrl(){ return serverRootUrl; }
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext){
        this.serverRootUrl=servletContext.getRealPath("/");
    }
}
```

Now just inject that Bean into your Quartz job class and use `serverConfig.getServerRootUrl()` to retrieve the root URL.

Comment: From the javadoc of ServletContext.getRealPath:

"The real path returned will be in a form appropriate to the computer and operating system on which the servlet container is running, including the proper path separators. This method returns null if the servlet container cannot translate the virtual path to a real path for any reason (such as when the content is being made available from a .war archive)."

Are you sure it's not going to return you something like `C:\tomcat\webapps\...` ?

Comment: @artbristol no I am not sure. but I don't see a better method in there

Comment: Possibly a single servlet can serve multiple hostnames (like with virtual hosting) so you can't get the hostname from the ServletContext. Thought I should really just try running the method to find out :-)

Comment: So I tested this approach, it returns me something like `C:\jboss\webapps\MyCrappyApp\...` calling `servletContext.getResource("/")` does most of the job, thanks for putting me on the right track :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getRequestURL()` and parse that to get the host name, if you have an `HttpServletRequest` object at the time you start the Quartz job.

Comment: On the other hand: *if you have an HttpServletRequest object at the time you start the Quartz job* you should take a large hammer and whack yourself on the head with it

Comment: Well, the job might be starting as a result of some HTTP request, but yeah, you would expect there to be several layers in between. Is that what you're saying?